# Can't SSH into my Mac from Linux

Tags: network, unix, ssh, server.app

I seem to be having a problem with trying to ssh into my Mac from a Linux desktop. I have two users on my Mac and can ssh between them, but other computers seem to be the problem.

I enabled remote login in System Preference > Sharing. It tells me to try "ssh username@192.168.x.x", but when I try that it does not work, likewise when I try using ssh -p22.

Later I generated an RSA file using ssh-keygen in the Linux desktop and added it into the Mac's authorized_keys file. Please note that I am able to ssh into the Linux desktop without any problem.And my firewall is off on the mac.

I do not even get prompted to enter the password, it just does nothing for some time and then later displays:-

```
ssh -p22 username@192.168.x.x

ssh: connect to host 192.168.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

I know I am connected to the internet. This is the verbose output:

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to 192.168.x.x [192.168.x.x] port 22.

debug1: connect to address 192.168.x.x port 22: Connection timed out

ssh: connect to host 192.168.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be? What other steps can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting timeouts, that has nothing to do with your authentication mechanism - whether password, or key based.

The timeout means either you can't connect to the Mac at all, or it's not accepting traffic on port 22 (the SSH port)

Some things to check -

- Have you checked your firewall is off on the mac? System Preferences -> Security -> Firewall
- Can you ping the Mac from the Linux desktop? A simple ping to the Mac will verify that they're on the same network and can communicate.

Fix your network issue before you try to fix your authentication.

Comment: yes, the firewall is off......but I did try to ping it ...... I tried the IP address show in in the remote login screen of system preferences and also the IP address shown in by google ..... nothing is happening......just static

Comment: Hey..... I came home and I used putty on my windows computer that is on the same network and tried to connect to my mac and it worked like butter.....So I assume that the computers in my local wifi network can connect between them...but how can I connect my linux desktop that is in my office to my mac.....both are connected to the internet and switched on.

Comment: So these computers are on different networks?

Comment: yes...these computers are on different networks.....if I connect to a computer on the same network it works fine,,,,what should I do to connect to the mac from a different network?

Comment: You need to ensure that your access to point to your network that is receiving the connection is configured to receive and forward to the correct host. This is normally configured in the NAT or port-forwarding settings of your router. You'll need to forward port 22 to your server.

Comment: HELLDOZER Did you ever figure this issue out? @Alex How would one go about setting the router up for this? I follow the steps in: https://kb.netgear.com/24290/How-do-I-add-a-custom-port-forwarding-service-on-my-Nighthawk-router but still have issues--the same issues as mentioned above. Do I have to setup anything special on the Linux machine I am using to ssh into my router > iMac? Or do I only need to set it up on my router?

Comment: @d84_n1nj4 - depends on where your networks are. 192.168.*.* is an internal network subnet, and isn't routable over the internet, so you need either a VPN or some other way to connect them. If your port forwarding is enabled on your router, you need to hit the router's IP from your external machine, not the internal IP the server has.

Comment: @Alex you’re correct, I hit my routers ip address and it fixed my issue. Then I was worried about security and posted this https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325659/289154 . I haven’t received much feedback so I posted this as well, https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/33166/ssh-and-port-forwarding-with-pia-from-ubuntu-remote-to-imac-host . If you can, please read over those posts and let me know what I can do. Apologies, I’m new to most of this technology.

Comment: @d84_n1nj4 - 1) disable password auth, and use keys only. 2) Don't open up your router, just your server. 3) Work out if you really need the access, vs having yourself exposed.

Comment: @Alex to give you some context, I have Ubuntu installed on a phone. I want to use it to log into my iMac, boot up my Ubuntu VM via virtual box(my hadoop environment), then ssh into my VM. I'm always on the go, so it's nice to be able to work with my hadoop environment while I'm on the go.